# $f$ is differentiable twice but not in $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be differentiable twice in any punctured neighborhood of 0. Is $f$ necessarily differentiable at 0?

How can I show or prove such a thing? Does it mean that the derivative is subtracted by $x$ and therefore is not defined for 0? Maybe I am wrong and a function non differentiable at some point is a function that in some point become constant? Really confused here... :(

Comment: Maybe I understand wrong your problem, but take any _nice_ function $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (as $x \mapsto x^2$) and define $g \colon x\neq 0 \mapsto f(x), 0\mapsto f(x)+1$. Then $g$ is differentiable many times in any punctured neighbourhood of $0$, but $g$ isn't even continuous in $0$.

Comment: Is $g(0)=1$ as I understood?

Comment: If you take $f$ to be $x \mapsto x^2$, yes, then $g(0)=1$.

Comment: In that case, g don't even get $0$.?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, btw.